# Better solution to get column from Relationship with Main Model columns

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, jenssegers-mongodb

**Need a better solution**

There is a `Post` which belongs to multiple `Categories` and both having Many-to-Many relationship in between them. The intermediate table for many-to-many relationship is `PostCategory`. `PostCategory` contains `post_id`, `category_id` and `sequence` of the post. I want to get this `sequence` with the `Post` model attributes (title, description, ...).

To get this, am doing like this

```php
$posts = Post::where([
    'is_active' => 1,
    'is_deleted' => 0,
    'is_published' => 1,
    'status' => 'publish'
])->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($params) {
    return $query->where([
        'category_id' => $params['categoryId'],
    ]);
})->with([
    'category' => function ($query) use ($params) {
        return $query->where([
            'category_id' => $params['categoryId'],
        ]);
    }
])
    ->orderBy('live_date', 'DESC')
    ->orderBy('publish_time', 'DESC')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
    
foreach ($posts as &$post) {
    $post['sequence'] = $post['category']['sequence'];
}
```

Am getting the expected result but as you can see, first I've to use the closure twice and then have to iterate through entire collection to set `sequence` at the top-level but as I mentioned, I need a better solution to this (If any)

**Post.php**

```php
namespace App\Models\Mongo;


/**
 * @mixin \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 * @mixin \Jenssegers\Mongodb\Query\Builder
 */
class POST extends \Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model
{
    /** @var string Mongo Connection Name */
    //protected $connection = 'mongodb';

    /** @var string Mongo Collection Name */
    protected $collection = 'posts';

    /** @var bool Enable/Disable Timestamp */
    public $timestamps = true;

    /** @var string Date format */
    protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

    /** @var array */
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'live_date', 'expire_date'];

    /**
     * // I know this relation is not correct, it must either belongsToMany or hasMany
     * // but as of now, I've to fetch the posts belonging to a single category id
     * // so using hasOne relation
     * @return \Jenssegers\Mongodb\Relations\HasOne
     */
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(
            PostCategory::class,
            'post_id',
            '_id'
        );
    }
}
```

**PostCategory.php**

```php
namespace App\Models\Mongo;


/**
 * @mixin \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 * @mixin \Jenssegers\Mongodb\Query\Builder
 */
class PostCategory extends \Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model
{
    /** @var string Mongo Connection Name */
    //protected $connection = 'mongodb';

    /** @var string Mongo Collection Name */
    protected $collection = 'post_category';

    /**
     * @return \Jenssegers\Mongodb\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class, '_id', 'post_id');
    }
}
```

**Changes**

change relation to `belongsToMany` in `Post`

Relation is not working

```php
return $this->belongsToMany(
    Category::class,
    'post_category',
    'post_id',
    'category_id',
    '_id', <-- post primary key
    '_id', <-- category primary key
)->withPivot('sequence');
```

Comment: You can store the closure in a variable and re-use it

Comment: Whether I store the closure in a variable or not, both ways closure will be used twice and using closure twice is not a problem, problem is I've to iterate through entire collection just for that `sequence`

Comment: Maybe my answer is better then.

Comment: Ok, let me give it a try

Comment: @shaedrich after changing relationship to `belongsToMany` its not working at all. I've added the changed relationship in the question, If you can check that will be great.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working at all"? Did you get any error message?

Comment: Nope, am getting empty collection after changing the relation

Comment: My bad, can't use `belongsToMany` in `whereHas`

Comment: Hard to say without seing the actual sql statement. Honestly, Laravel drove me crazy with its relationship syntax a dozen times :D Could you `$sql = $query->toSql();
dd($sql);`?

Comment: Who says you cannot use `whereHas` there? Do you want to filter the pivto table?

Comment: 1. `toSql` doesn't provide the relationship queries, still here is the query 
`select * from "posts" where ("is_active" = ? and "is_deleted" = ? and "is_published" = ? and "status" = ?) and "_id" in (?, ?) order by "" , ""`
2. Yes, we can't use any `belongsTo` relation in `whereHas` method
3. Just a note, am using Eloquent outside laravel with Jenssengers Mongodb and all these models are mongo collection models

Comment: I'm afraid, I am at my wit's end. I'm confident, we're heading in the right direction but without fiddling around with that myself, I bet, I couldn't see what must be changed in my answer to make it fit with your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure) instead and access `sequence` as [pivot column](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns).

```php
namespace App\Models\Mongo;


/**
 * @mixin \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 * @mixin \Jenssegers\Mongodb\Query\Builder
 */
class POST extends \Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model
{
    /** @var string Mongo Connection Name */
    //protected $connection = 'mongodb';

    /** @var string Mongo Collection Name */
    protected $collection = 'posts';

    /** @var bool Enable/Disable Timestamp */
    public $timestamps = true;

    /** @var string Date format */
    protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

    /** @var array */
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'live_date', 'expire_date'];

    /**
     * // I know this relation is not correct, it must either belongsToMany or hasMany
     * // but as of now, I've to fetch the posts belonging to a single category id
     * // so using hasOne relation
     * @return \Jenssegers\Mongodb\Relations\HasOne
     */
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Category::class
        )->withPivot('sequence');
    }
}
```

You probably have to add one or more optional parameters to `belongsToMany()` to make it work. But since you know your data structure better than I do, I bet, you can figure that out faster than I can.